# Import HTML meta tag elements when uploading an html file to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there an option to upload an HTML file with meta tags to Google Drive and have the meta data shown in the document (need to convert the file to Google Drive since I need to edit it)

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, XHTML, JavaScript">
        <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials on HTML and CSS">
        <meta name="author" content="AngryBird">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this feature is not available in Google Drive. You can apply the metadata yourself later using the Google Drive SDK, e.g. the `description` field, but this will not be done automatically.